# Complex polynomials converging in the compact-uniform topology

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Suppose that $p_n$ are polynomials with degree $n$, with $p_n(0)=1$ and which converges uniformly on compact sets of $\mathbb{D}$ towards an analytic function $f$.
Now, suppose that the $p_n$ have no roots in a disk of radius strictly greater than 1, say - for simplicity - $D(0,2)$.

Is it true that one can *extend* the uc convergence to all compacts of the disk $D(0,2)$ ?  Or in any intermediary disk $D(0, r)$ for some $1<r<2$ ? What would be simple assumptions on the $p_n$ to ensure such a behaviour (on the coefficients, the roots, on $f$...) ?

**Answer**. As answered above by Sangchul, the answer to the first question is no. He gave a counterexample.

**Edit: a possible other formulation**. By taking the inverses $z \to p_n(z)^{-1}$, whose radii of convergence are greater than $2$,  and using the Hurwitz theorem, the question becomes: we have a sequence of rational functions with no poles in $D(0, 2)$ which takes the value $1$ at zero, and which converges uniformly on compact sets of $D(0, 1)$ towards an analytic function $g=f^{-1}$. The radius of convergence $R$ of $g$ is greater than or equal to $1$. Is it possible that $R=1$ ? If not, $R>1$; then, does the uniform convergence of $1/p_n$ towards $g$ holds (uniformly on compact sets) for some disk $D(0, s)$ with $1<s<R$ ?

Comment: I presume you're requiring $f$ to be an entire function here? Otherwise something like $f(z) = 1/(z-r)+C$ where $1<r<2$ would show this doesn't work.

Comment: @Glare, What kind of polynomial sequence $(p_n(z))$ do you have in your mind for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-r}+C$? The typical Taylor series will not work, since its degree $n$ Taylor series about $z=0$, $$C-\frac{1}{r}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^k}{r^k}=C+\frac{1-(z/r)^{n+1}}{z-r}$$ will have many zeros on $D(0,2)$.

Comment: @Glare : no. Suppose that the limiting $f$ is equal to $z \to (z-r)^{-1}+c$ for some $c$ and some $r$ between $1$ and $2$. Then the question becomes, in this context : is there an $1<s<r$ such that the convergence $p_n \to f$ holds uniformly on compact sets of $D(0, s)$ ?

Comment: @SangchulLee You're right, I wasn't being careful enough about the "no zeroes in $D(0,2)$" condition. (Though the location of the zeroes of that Taylor polynomial isn't immediately obvious to me)

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, I don't think the degrees of the polynomials in $(p_n)_{n\geq 1}$ are uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, we will construct a counter-example. First, note that it suffices to find a sequence $(q_k)_{k\geq 1}$ of polynomials satisfying:

- $0 < \deg q_1 < \deg q_2 < \deg q_3 < \dots $;
- $q_k(0) = 1$;
- Each $q_k$ has no roots in $D(0, 2)$;
- $q_k$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$;
- $q_k(1)$ does not converge.

Then we can construct $(p_n)_{n\geq 1}$ by letting $p_n(z) = q_k(z) + \epsilon_n z^n$ for $\deg q_k \leq n < \deg q_{k+1}$ and for some $\epsilon_n \geq 0$ chosen sufficiently small.

**Construction.** For each $k \geq 1$, choose $q_k(z)$ as the Taylor polynomial of $e^{z+z^2+\dots+z^k}$ with degree large enough so that

$$ \sup_{z \in D(0,2)} \left| q_k(z) - e^{z+z^2+\dots+z^k} \right| < e^{-2^{k+1}} $$

as well as $\deg q_k > \deg q_{k-1}$ if $k \geq 2$. Then for $z \in D(0, 2)$,

$$ \left| q_k(z) \right| > \left| e^{z+z^2+\dots+z^k} \right| - e^{-2^{k+1}} \geq e^{-2-2^2-\dots-2^k} - e^{-2^{k+1}} > 0, $$

and so, $q_k$ has on zero on $D(0, 2)$. Moreover, since $e^{z+z^2+\dots+z^k}$ converges to $e^{z/(1-z)}$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$, the same is true for $q_k$. Finally, since $\left| q_k(1) - e^{k} \right| < e^{-2^{k+1}}$, it follows that $q_k(1)$ diverges as $k\to\infty$.